# Favicon not served in Ghost blog on Azure

Tags: azure, ghost-blog

I am trying to use a custom favicon on my Ghost blog which is running on Azure websites.

Following [this blog](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-add-a-favicon-to-your-ghost-blog/) I have:

- set the favicon location to `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset "/favicon.ico"}}">` in `default.hbs`
- put the image inside the `assets` folder for the default caspar theme (the theme I am using).

When the app restarts I get a 404 if I browse to `/assets/favicon.ico` & the default Ghost favicon is displayed.

**Note:** I have cleared browser cache

I think this might be an IIS permissions issue? Can anybody help?

Comment: how are you running it? VM or Azure Websites?

Comment: Azure Websites..

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to upload your favicon.ico to the `assets` folder (as you guessed). Nothing needs to change regarding IIS or permissioning.

I just tested this to verify, and it worked. My exact theme asset path in my Azure Web App (formerly known as Azure Websites), as seen via kudu:

`D:\home\site\wwwroot\content\themes\casper\assets>`

I just ftp'd into my site, navigated to `site\wwwroot\content\themes\casper\assets`, switched to `binary` transfer mode, and put the `favicon.ico` file there.

[image: Assets directory]

Then I pulled up default.hbs via kudu in browser, and modified the icon link, just as you did:

[image: default.hbs]

The last thing I did: I cleared out my browser cache and history for my blog, then re-loaded it. And... My new icon appeared. I created a doodle for the icon, for testing purposes, which now pops up in my browser tab:

[image: browser tab]

FYI I'm not sure if you're using kudu (which is `https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net`) - it makes it very easy to navigate. Just visit there and open a cmd window (under the Debug Console menu).

Comment: As I stated in my post I have set the favicon link and put the favicon in the assets folder. I should have mentioned the first thing I did was clear the cache...

Comment: I figured maybe there was a missed step. :) By the way... did you restart your web app after modifying default.hbs?

Comment: Yes I did restart the app. I'm sure it's a permissions issue - as I mentioned the image at hostname/assets/favicon.ico (i.e. the path set in default.hbs) gives a 404